# deploy octopress to heroku always return blank page

Tags: heroku, octopress

This is my first time using Octopress, I follow the [tutorial](http://www.jackiejohnston.us/blog/setting-up-an-octopress-blog-on-heroku/) I cannot deploy my Octopress app to heroku. When I do, all I get is a blank page.

I finally check the logs.

```
2014-10-21T03:48:02.793139+00:00 heroku[run.8368]: Process exited with status 1
2014-10-21T03:48:02.796400+00:00 heroku[run.8368]: State changed from up to complete
2014-10-21T03:48:05.012590+00:00 heroku[run.5502]: Starting process with command `false && AUTOMATED DIAGNOSIS BEING RUN BY HEROKU SUPPORT; cat config/environments/production.rb`
2014-10-21T03:48:04.976958+00:00 heroku[run.5502]: Awaiting client
2014-10-21T03:48:05.373361+00:00 heroku[run.5502]: State changed from starting to up
2014-10-21T03:48:06.136217+00:00 heroku[run.5502]: Process exited with status 1
2014-10-21T03:48:06.152972+00:00 heroku[run.5502]: State changed from up to complete
2014-10-21T04:04:36.113302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=passol.herokuapp.com request_id=060acfa7-179f-4388-8baa-6f494eb7da48 fwd="61.141.70.22" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=283
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I finally find the answer.I have to remove public and Gemfile.lock from .gitignore and at least one blog